# When does the Google Maps Android SDK first use the internet?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm making an app that includes a Google Maps fragment (SupportMapFragment). I created the activity using the templates in Android studio so the relevant pieces of code look like [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/BasicMapDemoActivity.java). I'm trying to figure out where I first need to request user permissions for Internet access in order to be compatible with the Android 6.0 permission system. Currently I'm checking for user permissions on the `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` call just to be safe.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to ask for permissions to use the internet. You do need to ask permission to use Location calls

Comment: no problem.  It is confusing the first few times working with permissions.